# correct way to re-call backgroundworker

Tags: c#

As in title, I have some bgw I want to call on every button press.
Is this code correct ?

```
private static BackgroundWorker bgw = null;
private void bttn_Click(...)
{
   if(!bgw.IsBusy)
      doSomeWorkInBg();
   else
      MessageBox.Show("Slow down a bit");
}

private void doSomeWorkInBg()
{
     if (bgw == null)
        {
            bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        }
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // do some work that takes time
}
```

Or maybe I should add RunWorkerCompleted event with "bgw = null;" code or something like that?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Does the code work? If so, then your question is more appropriate on codereview.stackexchange.com. If it doesn't work, please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, along with a clear explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: If your background worker does the same kind of task always, I'd suggest you use `ThreadPool` since it's memory efficient and easy to handle.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same task always. Also, the code seems to be working, but I had some problems with bgw class in my other program so I wanted to make sure that I'm using it correctly this time.
The main question was: Is there any need to "reset" or dispose worker manually after it does it's DoWork event to safely re-call it again.
I'm gonna check how does ThreadPool work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should avoid making your `bgw` static, because you are using it in non-static context.
2. When I need to re-run the worker frequently based on the UI event, this is the construct that I usually use:

> ```
> bool ShouldRunWorkedASAP;
>
> private void bttn_Click(...){
>  ShouldRunWorkedASAP=true;
>  if (!bgw.IsBusy) bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
> }
>
> private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
> {
>    while (ShouldRunWorkedASAP) {
>      ShouldRunWorkedASAP=false;
>      // do some work that takes time
>    }
> }
> ```

This assumes that the worked is instantiated in the class constructor. Basically this code sets the flag that the worker should run ASAP whenever the UI event occurred, then tries to run the worker. If it is already running - then the while() loop inside the worker implementation will schedule the job for the next run as soon as it completes.

This code does not ensure that the worker will run exactly the number of times the user presses the button, not sure if in your case this is required or not.